# is there a meaningful interpretation of the significance in cross-country correlation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample

By cross-country meaning we are not sampling countries, but using the whole "population of countries" in the analysis?

More generally, should one report the p-values in analyses where the cases are not a sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact values of some parameter then you don't need to report things like p-values or margins of error. For instance, if you know the mean height of the whole population of people on Earth you won't need to apply an error, because that's only done in the case of sampling like you said.

Although! Do check out this conversation here: http://andrewgelman.com/2009/07/03/how_does_statis/